# How update icu lib for php7?

Tags: php, icu, intl

I try update icu lib on version 59. In system `icuinfo` show right version - 59. But in phpinfo i see version 50.

Icu i install by [this](http://www.icu-project.org/repos/icu/tags/release-59-1/icu4c/readme.html#HowToBuildUNIX) manual.

```
./runConfigureICU Linux --prefix=/opt/icu59/
gmake && gmake install
```

Pecl `intl` not install, `intl` - installed like package `php70u-intl.x86_64`. Variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH for system and php-fpm added (in phpinfo it show). But version not changed.

php -v:

> PHP 7.0.20 (cli) (built: Jun 8 2017 09:31:29) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>   with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v6.0.9, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
>   with Zend OPcache v7.0.20, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
>   with Xdebug v2.5.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans

OS:

> NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
>   VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
>   ID="rhel"
>   ID_LIKE="fedora"
>   VERSION_ID="7.3"
>   PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.3 (Maipo)"
>   ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
>   CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:server"
>   HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
>   BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
>
> REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
>   REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.3
>   REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
>   REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.3"
>   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
>   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

Answer (score 0):

download url： http://site.icu-project.org/download/59

http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/59.1/icu4c-59_1-src.tgz

tar zxf  icu4c-59_1-src.tgz

cd icu/source
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/icu）make && make install